# Bootstrap table 'data-checkbox' property is not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, blazor

I have a Bootstrap table in my Blazor project and would like to include the data-checkbox property. I have added the required links and scripts, but no checkbox column appears. I also tried downloading the source code and linking to that.

I've managed to get the bootstrap-select plugin to work, so I'm not sure why bootstrap-table isn't working for me.

Here is my HTML in the _Host.cshtml file.

Head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap-select-1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
```

Body:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.